# Can a Google Apps Script Web App get the user's language and time zone?

Tags: localization, google-apps-script

Is there any possibility for a GAS published as a Web App executing under the identity of the active user and using the Ui Service for user interface to get the preferred language and time zone of the user?
`Session.getActiveUser()` works but you only get the Email `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`.
`Session.getTimeZone()` returns the time zone of the script, not of the user.

Could there be a trick to get the web browser ID string with the language preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Session.getActiveUserLocale()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUserLocale()) was introduced in 2014 to provide this capability.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting question. I think the short answer is that there is no good way for now and you have to ask the users for their locale/language.

I don't see a way to do this on the server side using the APIs you've already discussed. However, I was thinking maybe there is a clever way to do this on the client side and send send it up to the server using the [google.script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service?hl=en#GoogleScriptAPI) API after getting the locale information from the [navigator.language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.language) JS call.

Unfortunately, since the HTML/JS you have in your web app gets sanitized for security through [Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/), only portion of the normal [window.navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator) properties are exposed. It seems the only useful [properties](http://code.google.com/searchframe#wBZsFl6bRv8/trunk/src/com/google/caja/plugin/domita.js&l=4361) are userAgent, and platform. Language seems innocuous enough to expose, so this is worth logging a request in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: I opened one: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2310 - Please star if you are interested in this as well.