# Localization : Get language and country code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, localization

I am developing an editor addon and wanted to localize my menus.

I have looked at [Can a Google Apps Script Web App get the user's language and time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427764/can-a-google-apps-script-web-app-get-the-users-language-and-time-zone) and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuserlocale

In Google Sheets, to change Display language, we need to set both language and country.

[image]

Clicking on English will redirect to a page where we need to select language followed by country.

[image]

With Session.getActiveUserLocale(), I can get the language (en) but not the country (US).

Any references on how to get this done would be helpful.

Comment: How do you have your add-on? I have tried using only `Session.getActiveUserLocale();` on a test script and it returns the full `en_US`. Could it be related to this issue on Google Issue tracker [Session.getActiveUserLocale() not working consistently in the new Apps Script IDE](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179563675?pli=1)?

Comment: I have tried Session.getActiveUserLocale() in onOpen() as well as on a menu click. Both the times it returned "en"

Comment: Have you tried it in a standalone script without a menu or an onOpen? Just a simple function.

Comment: Tried with a standalone script and **Session.getActiveUserLocale()** still returns **"en"**

Comment: `function myFunction() {
  Browser.msgBox(Session.getActiveUserLocale());
}`

Comment: Can you try it like this `function test() {   Logger.log(Session.getActiveUserLocale()); }` in a standalone script and see if this returns the same?

Comment: Tried. I still see "en".  @Kessy, are you seeing "en-US" with above code?

Comment: Yes the result with the code on my previous comment returns "en-US", can you share the manifest file for your script and more details on how your account is set up to see if there is any difference? Please avoid sharing personal information.

Comment: {
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}

Comment: Tried this as well... `{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}`

Comment: @Putta, I've had the same experience — that's how I ended up on this page. Somehow changing the locale of the spreadsheet that contains the code a few times changed it. It was just "en," and now it's "en_us." I wish I could tell you what exactly changed it, but I don't know myself.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this on my end no matter what I tried.

You can create an issue on [Google's Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) and see if they can reproduce this.

You can follow the template for Apps Script:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905